# Clean data in SQL which has hierarchy in one cell. Eg Building > Wing > Floor > Ground .I want category, sub-category & break down into columns

Tags: sql, excel, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-cleaning

|How can I clean data which has hierarchy in one cell.

```
Eg 1. Sector 1 > Building 123 > Wing B > Ground Floor
Eg 2. Sector 2 > Building 123 > wing A
```

Expected o/p

| Sector | Building | wing | floor |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | B | Ground floor |  |
| 2 | 123 | A | null |  |

I want category, sub-category & break down into columns.This clean up of data needs to be done in Sq.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SPLIT_PART()` to get the string and then use `replace` to remove the extra strings.

Full SQL below

```
select 
replace(SPLIT_PART('Sector 1 > Building 123 > Wing B > Ground Floor','>',1),'Sector ') as Sector,
replace(SPLIT_PART('Sector 1 > Building 123 > Wing B > Ground Floor','>',2),'Building ') as Building
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the previous answer a little bit:

```
---dataset
set string_one = 'Sector 1 > Building 123 > Wing B > Ground Floor';
set string_two = 'Sector 2 > Building 123 > wing A';

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE my_table_test (
  sector varchar,
  building varchar,
  wing varchar,
  floor varchar default null
);

insert into my_table_test values (
SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART($string_one, ' > ', 1), ' ', 2),
SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART($string_one, ' > ', 2), ' ', 2),
SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART($string_one, ' > ', 3), ' ', 2),
SPLIT_PART($string_one, ' > ', 4)
);

insert into my_table_test values (
SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART($string_two, ' > ', 1), ' ', 2),
SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART($string_two, ' > ', 2), ' ', 2),
SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART($string_two, ' > ', 3), ' ', 2),
SPLIT_PART($string_two, ' > ', 4)
);


select * from my_table_test
```

[image]